# Why am I not getting hystrix metrics?

Tags: java, spring-boot, monitoring, netflix, hystrix

I am trying to use hystrix to monitor a certain network call. But all the metrics I try to monitor are always empty. What am I doing wrong?

I simulate a network call by implementing a (somewhat) RESTful interface that returns a pow calculation:

```
GetPowerCommand gpc = new GetPowerCommand(5, 82);
powerMetrics = gpc.getMetrics();
```

This is how I call the hystrix command and expect to get some metrics (at least Requests: not 0)

```
boolean run = true;
while (run) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        run = false;
    }
    System.out.println("GetPowerCommand.run(): " + gpc.run());
    System.out.println("GetPowerCommand.run(): " + gpc.run());
    System.out.println("getStatsStringFromMetrics(powerMetrics): " + getStatsStringFromMetrics(powerMetrics));
}
```

But all I get is:

```
GetPowerCommand.run(): <p>I guess .. </p><p>2^5 = 32</p>
GetPowerCommand.run(): <p>I guess .. </p><p>2^5 = 32</p>
getStatsStringFromMetrics(powerMetrics): Requests: 0 Errors: 0 (0%)   Mean: 0 50th: 0 75th: 0 90th: 0 99th: 0 
GetPowerCommand.run(): <p>I guess .. </p><p>2^5 = 32</p>
GetPowerCommand.run(): <p>I guess .. </p><p>2^5 = 32</p>
getStatsStringFromMetrics(powerMetrics): Requests: 0 Errors: 0 (0%)   Mean: 0 50th: 0 75th: 0 90th: 0 99th: 0
```

edit: my metrics retrieval method:

```
private static String getStatsStringFromMetrics(HystrixCommandMetrics metrics) {
    StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder();
    if (metrics != null) {
        HealthCounts health = metrics.getHealthCounts();
        m.append("Requests: ").append(health.getTotalRequests()).append(" ");
        m.append("Errors: ").append(health.getErrorCount()).append(" (").append(health.getErrorPercentage())
                .append("%)   ");
        m.append("Mean: ").append(metrics.getTotalTimeMean()).append(" ");
        m.append("50th: ").append(metrics.getExecutionTimePercentile(50)).append(" ");
        m.append("75th: ").append(metrics.getExecutionTimePercentile(75)).append(" ");
        m.append("90th: ").append(metrics.getExecutionTimePercentile(90)).append(" ");
        m.append("99th: ").append(metrics.getExecutionTimePercentile(99)).append(" ");
    }
    return m.toString();
}
```

Comment: I might have a Solution here:
I think it is wrong to call `GetPowerCommand.run()`. I should call `GetPowerCommand.execute()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answered your question: use `execute()` instead of `run()`. Have a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781982/hystrix-ignores-timeout-on-run)